# Linux Shell Scripting for reading multiple files and running them

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, parallel-ssh

I am using a centos cluster in which I am running LAMMPS software for simulations. Now I have to run multiple files in a folder now each file has a similar type of subfiles i.e they contain 3 files 1. input data file(file.restart.3500000) 2. Script(in.open) 3. PBS file(to run code on sub-node rather than master node).

My need is to run all the files in a folder with a single command that is too parallel not in serial. i.e. I want the system to run all the files simultaneously not like the first file is completed and then it starts the second file.

[image][image]

Presently I have to go to individual folders and run the script which is very time consuming as I have to do this multiple files.

to run the file I give " qsub runme.pbs " command once in the folder. Since the content of all the files are the same so is possible to do something about it?

PS:- I am just a beginner in this domain of Linux so any help will be very useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run them all with a simple for loop, based on something like this:

```
cd /path/to/wherever
for d in D_[0-9]*/; do
  cd "$d"
  qsub runme.pbs
  cd ..
done
```

`qsub` submits each job to the job queue, and the cluster will run them as its scheduler allows.

Alternatively, use `pushd "$d"` and `popd` instead of `cd "$d"` and `cd -`.

There may be some tiny benefit to running each `qsub` in the background (with `qsub runme.pbs &`) but probably not, that's more likely to overload the scheduler with too much work all at once and slow things down.

Comment: Or `(cd "$d" && exec qsub runme.pbs)` to avoid having to restore the cwd and not run qsub if cd failed.

Comment: I haven't used this sort of setup in years, does `qsub` return immediately or will it wait until the job has finished running?

Comment: @terdon it's been ages since i worked with PBS or Torque too (I always preferred SLURM, anyway).   But `qsub` submits the job to the queue, then it exits - that's it's purpose.  It doesn't wait for the job to finish - it doesn't even know when it will start, let alone finish.   The scheduler runs the job according to its rules (timing, permissions, priorities, etc), and when it has the resources (cpu cores/threads, gpus, memory, etc) available for the job.   Anyway, that's why I think running `qsub` with `&` isn't needed and would probably be a bad idea.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.

Comment: I will try this solution and see. Thanks

Comment: Thankyou @cas slution provided works fine.